# SELECT dates within one season (between two dates, of any year)

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible in Oracle SQL to select rows where one column is  a date, and we want this date to be between two dates irrespective of the year.
For example if the interval is summer, i'd want to be able to have any dates bewteen 20th of june and 22nd of september, where the year can be 1999, 2000, 2018, 2897 etc.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to a string of the form MM-DD and compare that:

```
where to_char(col, 'MM-DD') between '06-20' and '09-22'
```